# npm install error. errno 4058

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-install

when I try to install dependencies for my package i receive the folowing error

```
npm WARN package@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\typeScript_react_webpack_app_template\node_modules\typescript
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\typeScript_react_webpack_app_template\node_modules\typescript' -> 'C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\typeScript_react_webpack_app_template\node_modules\.typescript.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-07T08_55_48_803Z-debug.log
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

if I install package as npm install typescript all works fine.
What can be solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> delete package-lock.json and run npm again

Check if node and npm is installed correctly

for checking type

npm -v

if no number came then install it properly.

If  any number cam then the npm is installed, then go ahead

Quick fix:-delete package-lock.json and try again

If above does not work, then do below steps

1) delete package-lock.json

2) open task manager and  shut down all nodejs process

3) run npm init or npm install

4) if not works, then restart your system